# can't ssh to linux machine from mac

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, osx-yosemite, sshd

I have 2 Amazon machines: A(Centos) and B(Ubuntu). I can access B only from A.

When I try to connect from my Mac machine to A and then to B, I get the following error:

```
[alexarsh@A ~]$ ssh alexarsh@B -v
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy -p 22 B
debug1: identity file /home/alexarsh/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexarsh/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexarsh/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexarsh/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexarsh/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexarsh/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexarsh/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexarsh/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 679600005
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

When I try to connect with ssh from Linux/Windows -> A -> B, I have no problem.

I had similar problem once and I solved it with: http://developers.mogdesign.eu/blog/node/13

But now it's seems it's not the case.

Do you have an idea how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The

```
   ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

is extremely difficult to diagnose. You may find [here](http://edoceo.com/notabene/ssh-exchange-identification) some suggestions, but there are also many other possible causes.

What really helps is logging into the server, and starting *sshd* by hand without letting it demonize itself, as follows:

```
    sudo service ssh stop && /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd &
```

This will spew out the error messages to the standard output; now go back to your MAC, try to ssh into the server,and see the error messages. These will be much more revealing than those client-side, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Hi. Already tried the things in the link. The problem is somewhere in ssh config or something. I can successfully login to A machine. The problem starts when I try to do ssh to B machine. Maybe something is going through the environment variables or something

Comment: @Alex Like I said, the best way to troubleshoot this is to star sshd in un-daemonized form...